# I got a code in c# if statement and just manually input it, but I got it wrong.

Tags: if-statement

This first code is correct, whenever I run it in the console it gives the correct result

```
if ((number > 10) || (number < 0))
            Console.WriteLine("Hey! The number should be 0 or more and 10 or less!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Good job!");
```

Whilst on this one, whenever I input an integer between 1-10 it just gives the "very wrong" statement.

```
if ((x > 10) || (x < 10))
            Console.WriteLine("Very wrong!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
```

Source is http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/if-statement/

Comment: Are you changing the name of the variable the input is stored in when you change the one in the `if` statement? If the input goes into `number`, but your `if` checks `x`, it could create this problem.

Comment: Think about the number 5. You're telling the compiler that if five is larger than ten or five is less than ten. The considition will always be true.

Comment: Oh yes definitely. I just put it as variable name "number" because it's on the link. But here in my VS it's variable name "x" :) Please try to run it. :(

Comment: Hi sir mikeTheLiar, I think it's not on the condition, but because whenever I comment the first code then run the second, it just read the wrong WriteLine

Comment: mikeTheLiar is not lying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will only ever show Correct! if your value is exactly 10.

Change:

```
if ((x > 10) || (x < 10))
```

To:

```
if ((x > 10) || (x < 0))
```

If you want the same logic as the first set of code you provided.